# Xcode <Flutter/Flutter.h> file not found, after adding Extension to project

Tags: flutter, xcode, flutter-ios-build

Recently i upgrade my Xcode to 15 and i face this error.this is my build phase, i dont know why i get this error i try many solution on stack overflow like recreate IOS dir but didn’t work..

i try this but didn’t  work

Backup Runner folder
Delete the ios folder
Go to a terminal and execute flutter create . in the flutter project folder
Paste your Runner folder back into the ios folder
pod deintegrate in the ios folder
pod install also in the ios folder
flutter clean in the flutter project folder
flutter pub get
flutter run

Answer (score 0):

i solved this i change built phase and now my project run on IOS and also create IOS build[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuwJG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).